Amazfit GTR 2 mini apps
I have a problem. I have Amazfit GTR 2, and yesterday I turned off Developer mode, and I saw "Mini apps" tab. I want to upload apps to my device, how can I do this?
I tried to do this with official guids, but I couldn't do this. Also I tried to scan quar codes from this site: "https://itaxreal.github.io/ZeppOSRep/#", but I have error "bluetooth channel is not available. Please try again later." Please, help.

The "Bluetooth channel is not available. Please try again later" error can appear if the watch is currently synchronizing data.
You should wait until it's no longer busy before installing apps using Developer Mode.
Also, yes if you see that error you're probably doing everything right, but the bluetooth channel is busy.
